# Failed to log in: the authentication servers are currently down for maintenance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So once a month I'm having this problem where I can't connect to any servers with 1.8 but I can with 1.9, this makes it so I can't play on the servers that are only for 1.8.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're receiving the message in the title, I don't think there's anything you can do except wait.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do anything except wait. It is strange however that it only was in 1.8 and not in 1.9. It could be possible that this is a bug from only one Minecraft server, as I've seen this problem multiple times with these sorts of protocol hacks.

Comment: Still not working but thx <3